# ASP NET Core .NET 6 and OData - how to return lowercase json

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, odata

Odata controllers in my project returns jsons with casing as it is in class so PascalCase.
I want to make them return json with camelCase props.

Controllers which don't use OData returns camelCase jsons by default.

To configure Odata I'm using `IMvcBuilder.AddOData()` method (extension method from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData`). All my OData controllers inherits from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Rounting.Controllers.ODataController` and methods have `[EnableQuery]` attribute

I guess I should chain `AddJsonOptions` method after that, but don't know what to pass there. Internet says it should be `opt => opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()`, but opt here is [JsonOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonoptions?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and doesn't have `SerializerSettings` property.

Edit: Chaining `.AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = System.Text.Json.JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase` after `AddOData` doesn't help.

Edit2: Adding `[JsonProperty]` attributes on model properties also doesn't help.

Edit3: I try to add custom `ODataSerializerProvider` by register it in 3rd argument of `AddRouteComponents`, but constructor isn't hit neither at app start nor endpoint call.

Comment: does EnableLowcamelcase() extension method on model builder work for you?

Comment: @SamXu Nope, I think `EnableLowerCamelCase()` just allows to query using lowercase properties' names when they are UpperCase on model

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Call **builder.EnableLowerCamelCase()**

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<User>("User");

            // => Add EnableLowerCamelCase here to resolve problem
            builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();
            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
```

Another way answered before is remove **AddRouteComponents()** call. But this will make Odata only return array data only. For example:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:5001/odata/$metadata#questions",
    "@odata.count": 30,
    "value": [
        {
            "name": "name 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "name 2"
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

To return only array data, and remove another properties:

```
[
        {
            "name": "name 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "name 2"
        },
        ....
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was using `AddRouteComponents` method and custom Edm model. Without it `AddJsonObject` chained method works. Described here: https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/main/docs/camel_case_scenarios.md